# Load a number from txt file and use it as object

Tags: php, string, object

I want to load a file with a number within it and use it as number(not as string). Is there any solution for this? The error I get

```
Call to a member function seek() on a non-object
```

My PHP Code

```
$in = fopen('emails.txt','r');
$out = fopen('currentposition.txt', 'r+');
$pos = file_get_contents('currentposition.txt');
$in->seek($number1); 
while($kw = trim(fgets($in))) {
    //my code
    $position = $in->current();
    fwrite($out, $position);
}

fclose($in);
fclose($out);
```

Comment: can you post a few lines of your `emails.txt` & `currentposition.txt` files

Comment: AFAIK `seek()` is a method of the `SplFileObject` object, but `fopen()` returns a resource, not an object.

Comment: [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)

Comment: fseek() **only** sets the position indicator of the referenced file - it's not a search function. Consider the manual [fseek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)

Comment: i use fseek because someone here suggested me to use it. The emails.txt contains a 200mb  emails and the currentposition is blank txt file.Actually i want to read the the emails.txt file and when i stop the the script i want to be able to continue reading the file from the line the script stopped.......

Comment: @user1346598: "i want to be able to continue reading the file from the line the script stopped", .... the next time you open the file again to read from it? Is that so? If YES, then I've totally misunderstood and will edit my answer correspondingly and with some code eventually ;)

Comment: yes i want to be able to read it from the time script stopped the next  time i will run the script...sorry for the misunderstanding Havelock

Answer (score 1):

The file

```
$ cat /tmp/ll
9
```

The script :

```
<?php

$x = file_get_contents("/tmp/ll");
echo $x + 10;
?>
```

The output :
    19

Answer (score 0):

Use `$pos` instead of `$number1`...?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message you're getting: it means you're calling a **method**, that is, an object's member function, for something which is not an **object** (in the sense of Object-Oriented Programming). `$in` is not an Object of a Class, only a `resource`.

**Edit**

Now I understand correctly the task you wanted to accomplish try this:

```php
// use w - to truncate when writing (overwrite), b - in case you ever run this on Windows
$recordFile = fopen('currentposition.txt', 'wbr');
$emailsFile = fopen('emails.txt', 'r');
$pos = trim(fgets($recordFile));
// if first time and there was no 0 in the currentposition.txt
if(!isset($pos))
    $pos = 0;

//set the pointer
fseek($emailsFile, $pos);

// read the contents;
$content = fread($emailsFile, filesize($emailsFile));

// get the current position of the file pointer
$pos = ftell($emailsFile);

// write the last position in the file
fwrite($recordFile, $pos);

fclose($recordFile);
fclose($emailsFile);
```

That should work, yet not tested, to be honest. I hope you get the general idea.

**Add**

The code above reads all the contents of the emails file at once, into one (string) varible. You could then split it using `\n` as a delimiter, something like `$allEmails = split('\n', $content);`  and have the emails in an array, through which you could loop.
Anyway, here is the same code but with `while` loop, that is, reading the file line by line - would be good for very large file (MBytes)

```
// use w - to truncate when writing (overwrite), b - in case you ever run this on Windows
$recordFile = fopen('currentposition.txt', 'wbr');
$emailsFile = fopen('emails.txt', 'r');
$pos = trim(fgets($recordFile));
// if first time and there was no 0 in the currentposition.txt
if(!isset($pos))
    $pos = 0;

//set the pointer
fseek($emailsFile, $pos);


// while end of file is not reached
while(!feof($emailsFile)){
    // read one line of the file and remove leading and trailing blanks
    $kw = trim(fgets($emailsFile));
    // .... do something with the line you've read
    // get the current position of the file pointer
    $pos = ftell($emailsFile);    
    // you don't need to write the position in the $recordFile every loop!
    // saving it in $pos is just enough
}

// write the last position in the file
fwrite($recordFile, $pos);

fclose($recordFile);
fclose($emailsFile);
```

Comment: i tried this but the script is not looping.....i have added the first 10 lines of the code you gave me outside the while and the other code inside the while......

Comment: OK, I've added a second way to do the same. I don't mean to sound patronising, but maybe you should also consider some more programming lessons / tutorials - full of them on the net ;) unless of course is some "stupid" homework for a class you *have to* attend :)